# Setting cache-control header for static file serving on nextjs default server

Tags: next.js

I am using the default nextjs server to run my nextjs program by this command `next start`.

However, I am not able to change the cache-control header for the files under the public folder.

Is there any method to set the cache-control header without setting the Custom Server?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is undocumented feature or bug, but it works. More info can be found here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers

Add config to you `next.config.js` file for example:

```js
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:all*(svg|jpg|png)',
        locale: false,
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'public, max-age=9999999999, must-revalidate',
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I believe this feature is now documented.

Comment: It is documented not to work for `Cache-Control`. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#cache-control

Comment: It doesn't work now

Answer (score 10):

Per [this bug report and discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/1791) the Next devs believe static file serving should only be used as a developer convenience, not in production, and hence they don't consider it a priority to add such features.

However, in the issue comments somebody has suggested a workaround using Express to detect requests that will end up serving static files. For example, if the Next.js route handler is the `handler()` method you can do this to set a one-year cache policy for *.woff font files:

```
  // this is a hack to make the cache headers friendlier..
  server.get('*.woff2?', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public,max-age=31536000');
    return handler(req, res);
  });
```

Comment: Please put the whole code example for the server file, I don't see how to apply this given no server file I have.

Comment: If you don't use a separate server.js file with Express (or similar API), you can not use this method.

Answer (score 2):

According to the NEXT. official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#cache-control) i.e.,

> You cannot set Cache-Control headers in next.config.js file as these will be overwritten in production to ensure that API Routes and static assets are cached effectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set the `max-age` and only for images, you can use [`minimumCacheTTL`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#minimumcachettl) in `next.config.js`, like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 31536000,
  },
}
```

Note that

> There is no mechanism to invalidate the cache at this time, so its best to keep `minimumCacheTTL low`. Otherwise you may need to manually change the `src` prop or delete `<distDir>/cache/images`.

This won't work if you're using [Static Image Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#local-images), because for those the filename includes a hash, so the server uses the [`immutable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#immutable) directive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Express as a custom server for Next.js, and this is how I set "Cache-Control" header for static files:

```
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
...
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", { maxAge: "365d" }));
server.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.match(".js|.css|.woff|.jpg|.png|.gif|.ttf")) {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=31536000"); // 365 days
  }
  next();
});
```