# Can I use a javascript file to generate inline javascript within nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a 3rd party script that requires me to define a global `window.varforthem` before they load. I took a look at the [nextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#inline-scripts) for this. It's done in a way where eslint and other plugins won't work aside from it being less readable for a long configuration object. If I use my public folder like `<Script src="/scripts/forthirdparty.js" />`, it gets slapped on the page without being optimized like the rest of the assets within `_next/static`. On top of that, the `max-age` header is set to 0 so my CDN doesn't cache that misc file. is there a better way to handle this? If not, how can I make sure my static file gets a custom max age?

I tried to use a regular `<script>` vs `<Script>` in the `<Head>` tag after Steve Tomlin's link below.

My inline scripts need some server config to work which makes it a bit more complicated.

```js
// earlier in the method
const conf = `window.config = ${JSON.stringify(pageProps.config)}`;
const { config: pageConfig } = pageProps;

// later on
<Head>
  <script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: conf,
    }}
  />
  <script src="/scripts/myfile.js" />
  <script src={pageConfig.third_party_script_url} />
</Head>
```

When I inspect the `<head>` tag in Chrome everything looks right. However nothing runs and I got the error `Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>.` After compiling the first load works. Refreshes fail. Not sure why it's rendering differently on server than client.

Comment: check this - see if it solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165852/next-js-implement-external-js-with-script

Comment: For the last part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66777286/11613622

Comment: Cool testing this all out in a minute. If the first comment doesn't work I can use the second :)

Comment: @SteveTomlin funny issue. I am updating question with some details now

Answer (score 1):

Writing an answer here for people that might not realize some timing issues that can arise with [Next.JS implement external ".js" with <script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165852/next-js-implement-external-js-with-script). My third party script manipulated the DOM. So sometimes it would do that before/after React detects DOM differences from server. The full solution was to use `<script>` tags in `<Head>` for my own scripts that just put configuration for the third party script. I kept the third party `<script>`s out of `<Head>` so they would be rendered at bottom of page after everything else ran.

Comment: Timing issues were fixed by the new `next/script` component. It ensures that scripts with the same strategy are loaded in order (and `beforeInteractive` scripts are run before `afterInteractive` and `lazyOnload` scripts). So, you could have just done --- ```<Script src="your script" strategy="beforeInteractive" /><Script src="third party script" />```  --- by default the strategy is `afterInteractive` i.e. scripts are injected on the client-side and will run after hydration. Note that you have to put `next/script` outside `next/head`.